# How to use ng-change on a select without ng-model

Tags: angularjs

The [`ngChange` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) requires `ngModel` to be present, but binding directly to a field in my controller is difficult, because the logic is a little more complicated.

I have a questionnaire containing questions retrieved from a database. Each question may have an answer already and I can retrieve that with a call to a method on the survey being viewed:

`vm.survey.GetCurrentAnswerIDForQuestionID(q.ID)`

When updating, it is difficult to bind directly to a property because if the answer isn't present I need to create an entity to store it, and if it is present then I change it or delete it (when the user selects the empty option).

So I figure that I need to call a method instead. Like this:

`vm.survey.SetCurrentAnswerIDForQuestionID(q.ID, answerid)`

I can display the select list correctly using this markup:

```
<select ng-init="answerid = vm.survey.GetCurrentAnswerIDForQuestionID(q.ID)">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option ng-repeat="va in q.ValidAnswers | orderBy:'SortOrder'"
          ng-selected="va.AnswerID === q.currentAnswer"
          value="{{va.AnswerID}}">
    {{va.Text}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Now I want to call a method to set the answer when the user changes the answer. Something like this:

```
        <select 
           ng-init="answerid = vm.survey.GetCurrentAnswerIDForQuestionID(q.ID)"
           ng-model="answerid" 
           ng-change="vm.survey.SetCurrentAnswerIDForQuestionID(q.ID, answerid)">
...etc
```

But that doesn't work - the correct item is no longer selected when I view the page

Comment: The model is incorrect on load or after a selection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using `ngOptions` to get the bindings to work correctly:

```
<select 
   ng-init="answerid = vm.survey.GetCurrentAnswerIDForQuestionID(q.ID)"
   ng-model="answerid" 
   ng-change="vm.survey.SetCurrentAnswerIDForQuestionID(q.ID, answerid)"
   ng-options="va.AnswerID as va.Text for va in q.ValidAnswers"
></select>
```

Comment: I had assumed my problem was that I wasn't allowed to use a variable initialised using `ng-init` as my model - not true, this works